# R markdown YAML dynamic variables

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

In RMarkdown, I seem to be able to create 'some' dynamic variables in the YAML header, but not for others:

For instance, this works:

```
---
title: 
  "Some Title, `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
...
---
```

But this does NOT.

```
---
...
pdf_document:
    keep_tex: `r 'true'`
---
```

But this DOES (ie not dynamic).

```
---
...
pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---
```

So how can I 'dynamically' assign the `keep_tex` to either true or false, what I want to do, is something like this:

```
---
...
pdf_document:
    keep_tex: `r getOption('mypackage.keep_tex')`
---
```

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if the template options can be set programmatically in the YAML header of the .Rmd file.

As an alternative, if you use `rmarkdown::render` to render your document, you may specify the output template (`pdf_document`), and then set template options (e.g. `keep_tex`) programmatically.

For example, if you have a .Rmd file called "test.Rmd" like this:

```
---
title: 
  "Some Title, `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
---
```

...and some logical object which determines whether to keep the intermediate TeX file or not, e.g.

```
my_keep <- TRUE
```

...you may render the input file to PDF format and keep the TeX file like this:

```
render(input = "test.Rmd",
       output_format = pdf_document(keep_tex = my_keep))
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. I should also say, after experimentation, if `pdf_document(...)` is used in preference to 'pdf_document' (ie function in preference to character string), then the function version will override anything specified in the YAML header.